# jQuery syntax error on line 1715

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a program and I updated the version of jQuery to 2.0.3 (same problem on 1.7.2) and now I am seeing an error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator jquery-2.0.3.js:1715
ot.error jquery-2.0.3.js:1715
gt jquery-2.0.3.js:2325
kt jquery-2.0.3.js:2712
ot jquery-2.0.3.js:1154
x.fn.extend.find jquery-2.0.3.js:5158
x.fn.x.init jquery-2.0.3.js:168
x jquery-2.0.3.js:63
i bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function) bootstrap.min.js:6
x.extend.each jquery-2.0.3.js:590
x.fn.x.each jquery-2.0.3.js:237
r bootstrap.min.js:6
x.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.3.js:4676
y.handle jquery-2.0.3.js:4360
```

Here is my source

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator/template/admin/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator/template/admin/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator/template/admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="" data-target="http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">System</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="" data-target="http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have trimmed the above HTML down to the minimum I need that still causes the problem. I hit it using jQuery 1.7.2 and 2.0.3, Bootstrap 2.3.2 and 3.0.3. I have not been able to find anything on Google that would give me any clues to why I am hitting this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `data-target="http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator" class="dropdown-toggle"` to do?

Comment: Debug your own code and find the line that's calling jQuery *just* before that error. Since we can't access `http://172.16.191.166`, we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: try to use not minified versions of your js, this should make your life easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess and say that Bootstrap isn't properly sanitizing selectors coming from data-target.  Since your attribute contains special characters per http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, they need to be sanitized.

From a cursory glance at Bootstrap's source, this seems to be the case.  I'd file a bug with Bootstrap and see if they agree, although they may tell you to escape the special characters in your attribute for them.

Comment: I'd gather the issue is that he's setting `data-target` to `http://172.16.191.166/system/administrator`.  I'm pretty sure that attribute isn't supposed to be a URL.

Comment: I don't think a bug is needed for not following their examples :) I removed the data-target attribute and all seems to be working. Thanks for the help